# Событие при наведении курсора на строку в таблице JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста на чистом JS с помощью `onmouseover` поменять фон строки таблицы при наведении на нее курсора (ховер не подойдет). Если бы это просто был какой-то `div` или что-то в этом роде, сработала бы конструкция типа `<div onmouseover="this.style.background='#000';">` Но я создаю строки программно и с этим у меня сложности... Спасибо!

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id),
    row = document.createElement("tr"),
    cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.className = 'checkbox_done';
  checkbox.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteRow(event)');

  var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
  btnEdit.type = 'image';
  btnEdit.className = 'btnEdit';
  btnEdit.src = 'icons/edit.png';
  btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editButton();
    return false;
  });

  var btnDelete = document.createElement("input");
  btnDelete.type = 'image';
  btnDelete.className = 'btnDelete';
  btnDelete.src = 'icons/delete.png';
  btnDelete.setAttribute('onclick', 'delButton(event)');

  var tdNum = document.createElement("td");
  tdNum.setAttribute('id', 'td1_id');
  tdNum.className = 'td_num';
  tdNum.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));

  var tdDone = document.createElement("td");
  tdDone.appendChild(checkbox);

  var tdItem = document.createElement("td");
  tdItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));

  var tdQuant = document.createElement("td");
  tdQuant.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));

  var tdPrice = document.createElement("td");
  tdPrice.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));

  var tdAction = document.createElement("td");
  tdAction.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
  tdAction.className = 'td_action';
  tdAction.appendChild(btnEdit);
  tdAction.appendChild(btnDelete);

  row.appendChild(tdNum);
  row.appendChild(tdDone);
  row.appendChild(tdItem);
  row.appendChild(tdQuant);
  row.appendChild(tdPrice);
  row.appendChild(tdAction);

  tbody.appendChild(row);

  localStorage.setItem('ShoppingList', document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML);
}

function editButton() {
  localStorage.setItem('DoneList', document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML);
}

function delButton(elemCheck) {
  var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
  var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);
  localStorage.setItem('DeleteList', document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML);
  localStorage.setItem('ShoppingList', document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
}

function deletedLS() {
  var DeleteList = localStorage.getItem('DeleteList');
  if (DeleteList !== null) {
    document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = DeleteList;
  }

}

function doneLS() {
  var DoneList = localStorage.getItem('DoneList');
  if (DoneList !== null) {
    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = DoneList;
  }
}

function indexLS() {
  var ShoppingList = localStorage.getItem('ShoppingList');
  if (ShoppingList !== null) {
    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = ShoppingList;
  }
}


function deleteRow(elemCheck) {
  var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
  var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);
  localStorage.setItem('ShoppingList', document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Cart - Shopping List</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icons/shortcut_add.ico" />
</head>

<body onload="indexLS();return false;" class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="li_index"><a class="link_index" href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="done.html">Done</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="h1">Shopping List</h1>
    <hr class="hr">
    <div class="inputs">
      <input class="input_add" type="text" id="add_id" placeholder="Add items to you Shopping List">
      <input class="input_quant" type="text" id="quant_id" placeholder="Quant.">
      <input class="input_price" type="text" id="price_id" placeholder="Price">
      <button class="input_button" type="button" onclick="insertRow('myTable');return false;">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <table class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <td class='td'>#</td>
          <td>Done</td>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Price $</td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100">Action</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
row.addEventListener("mouseover",function() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
})

row.addEventListener("mouseout",function() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
})
```

Код для теста

```js
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
  MakeRowHover(trs[i]);
}

function MakeRowHover(row) {
  row.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "silver";
  });

  row.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  });
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>заголовок</td>
      <td>заголовок</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1111111</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2222222</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3333333</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4444444</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5555555</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6666666</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: В принципе работает, но при этом теряется шапка таблицы, которая жестко создана в index.html. Ну и установил обход с первого элемента (var i = 1), опять же чтобы шапка таблицы в этом не учавствовала

Comment: @TheHateInMe просто вам надо искать не мо row а сделать класс для тех row которые вам нужны, сейчас в примере сделаю. На самом деле вам надо вставлять не мой код для примера, а в ваш код генерации, у вас там уже row есть, просто вставить мои функции.

Comment: @TheHateInMe добавил в пример.

Comment: @TheHateInMe если вам ответ подошёл, можете его отметить как ответ.

Comment: @TheHateInMe обновил ответ с более красивым решением в стиле новых стандартов HTML

Comment: если делать через addeventlistener, то после помещения в локалсторадж, обновление страницы с подгрузкой из хранилища, событие уже не отрабатывает...

Comment: @TheHateInMe тогда надо либо функцию инициализации onhover делать отдельно и каждый раз запускать после выборки из localStorage либо прямо в коде прописывать onmouseover и onmouseout.

Comment: а в чем разница между mouseover и onmouseover?

Comment: @TheHateInMe если прописывать как свойство внутри тегов html то идёт с "on" а если при прикрепке через addEventListener то без.

Comment: а как прописать прямо в коде? типа row.onmouseover = style.background="green" или как-то так....

Comment: @TheHateInMe `<tr onmouseover="RowOver" onmouseout="RowOut" >...</tr>` `RowOver` и `RowOut` эти функции вы сами должны написать

Comment: Сначала получил row из хранилища, а уже потом кинул на строки событие:
`function indexLS() {
    var ShoppingList = localStorage.getItem('ShoppingList');
           document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = ShoppingList;
   }
    
    var row = document.getElementsByClassName("row_class");    
[].forEach.call(row, function (row) {
        row.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#ececec";
        });
        row.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        });
    });
}`

Comment: По крайней мере так заработало.